# view.findViewById() returns null in one function but works fine in other one

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a TextView object using view.findViewById() in a function which is called when a button is clicked. In the onClickButton() null is returned whereas in other function setDefaultValues() it works fine.

Activity1.java

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final Double TIP = 10.0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);
        setDefaultValues();
    }

    private void setDefaultValues() {
        TextView tipView = findViewById(R.id.tipView);
       tipView.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_tip,Double.toString(TIP)));
    }

    public void onClickToggleButton(View view){
        TextView tipView = view.findViewById(R.id.tipView);
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case (R.id.toggleButtonBad):
                tipView.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_tip, Double.toString(BAD)));
                break;    
        }
}
```

When testing the app the following error message was shown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object referenceat com.example.chandan.learning.Activity1.onClickToggleButton
```

Edit : The `activity_1.xml` file does contain the `TextView` with `tipView` id so the theory that element is not present in the XML file is out of the window.

Comment: share your xml also

Comment: Remove  TextView tipView = view.findViewById(R.id.tipView); inside `onClickToggleButton`

Comment: Why are there **two** implementation of `tipView` ?
Remove the one from `onClickToggleButton`

Comment: @ManojPerumarath https://github.com/chandan00761/ERRORS/blob/master/activity_1.xml

Comment: @RakshitNawani Explanation to this beginner please

Comment: remove the `view.findViewById(R.id.tipView);` and change that whole line with this one `TextView tipView = findViewById(R.id.tipView);`. That `view` is button view object.

Comment: @ChandanMahto : You are passing the **View view** inside `onClickToggleButton` so it only give the id  of the Buttons in which the onClick is defined so it will not have the context of `tipView` so because of this it will give you NPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad practice to duplicate code. Now you have duplication of method `findViewById`. To avoid that, you should create a global variable in the class `Activity1`. That will also be solution of your problem:

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final Double TIP = 10.0;
    private TextView tipView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);
        setDefaultValues();
    }

    private void setDefaultValues() {
        tipView = findViewById(R.id.tipView);
        tipView.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_tip, Double.toString(TIP)));
    }

    public void onClickToggleButton(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case (R.id.toggleButtonBad):
                tipView.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_tip, Double.toString(BAD)));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find view from inside clicked view (Ex. Button), while the "tipView" is in main view container. So update your method "onClickToggleButton" as below:

```
    public void onClickToggleButton(View view) {
        TextView tipView = findViewById(R.id.tipView);
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case (R.id.toggleButtonBad):
             tipView.setText(getString(R.string.main_msg_tip, Double.toString(BAD)));
            break;
        }
    }
```